# Initial conditions on coupled PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

Consider the PDE in a 2D domain with boundary, $\Omega$ with Neumann boundary conditions for $u(x,y)$:

$u_{xx}f+u_{yy}f_x=0$

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}|_{\partial \Omega}=0$

where **both** $u(x,y)$ and $f(x,y)$ are unknown.

which boundary conditions (if any) do I need for $f$ for existence  and uniqueness (up to a constant) of $u(x,y)$ and $f(x,y)$ ?

Comment: The problem is that even for $f$ known (so the only unknown is $u$) the solution would not be unique. Indeed, if $u$ is a solution, any $\tilde u = u + C$ with $C$ a constant is a solution as well. In this case, you would usually add a constraint on the integral of $u$.

Comment: Also, what is an "initial" condition for you in this case? Is $x$ a "time" variable?

Comment: @G.Gare - thank you, corrected my question

Comment: @G.Gare No, it a spatial coordinate. Initial is just a general term